# Starting in DevExpress

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am looking at integrating DevExpress to a webapp Im doing in asp.net C#.
Finding it difficult to get a good article or book on how to begin. any where to find these?

Comment: I would recommend you to dig at demo on your devexpress installation. also help section on devexpress site

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of thing I used to get familiar with DX controlls:

1. As [Aseem Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499140/starting-in-devexpress/2499186#2499186)'s answer web casts gives good overall prospective
2. To get more detailed picture you can look through few sample apps
3. DX documentation, knowledge base
4. And finally you could ask for assistance the DevXpress support team

Answer (score 5):

you can find some demonstration here :

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASP/

Answer (score 4):

Professional DevExpress ASP.NET Controls by Wrox

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-DevExpress-ASP-NET-Controls.productCd-0470500832.html

Answer (score 3):

Best is to watch the online webcasts.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Downloads/#Documentation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

View the [online videos](http://tv.devexpress.com/) at the Developer Express site.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the devexpress site as the best source. They even have online demos that will help a lot.